# Recycleview with onclick assistance

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have tried a bunch of different methods now, and i haven't succeed to implement an Onclick method to my recycleview. My recycleview is working and showing my items.

Could someone assist me with implementation of an Onclick method in my recycleview?

Thx in advance.

//Dave

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ItemData[] itemsData;
public OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

public MyAdapter(ItemData[] itemsData) {
    this.itemsData = itemsData;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {



viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(itemsData[position].getTitle());
    viewHolder.imgViewIcon.setImageResource(itemsData[position].getImageUrl());


}

// inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView txtViewTitle;
    public ImageView imgViewIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
    }
}

// Return the size of your itemsData (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsData.length;
}
```

Here is the Item data:

```
public class ItemData {

private String title;
private int imageUrl;

public ItemData(String title,int imageUrl){

    this.title = title;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}
```

And my Fragment where the items are created:

```
public class MyMedicinFrag extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater i, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rod = i.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mymedicin, container, false);


    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rod.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    FloatingActionButton fabBtn = (FloatingActionButton) rod.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fabBtn.show();

    ItemData itemsData[] = {
            new ItemData("Panodil 500 mg", R.drawable.panodil),
            new ItemData("Ipren 200 mg", R.drawable.ipren),
            new ItemData("Madopar 200 mg", R.drawable.madopar),
            new ItemData("Diclofenac 50 mg", R.drawable.diclofenac),
            new ItemData("Allopurinol 300 mg", R.drawable.allopurinol)
    };

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(itemsData);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    return rod;

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `onCreateViewHolder()` use this code:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.myview, parent, false);

        view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                //do something on click
                }
            }
        });
```